# Canned vs Custom - Signed URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I need to serve private content through S3 and was wondering the differences between a canned and custom policy.

I know the docs state that canned is for a single object and custom can be for one or more objects, but i was wondering with custom, is the same rule applied to all objects.

In my application I need to secure around 100 PDF docs, each doc will have a different expiry time.

Now do I need to use custom, or will this not work as each doc has a different expiry time, so should I use canned for each doc individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a single custom policy it will not work for your use case. The times are a part of the policy, which means each one of your PDFs will need a different policy
So, unless you need the extra features available with custom policies, Canned is probably easier and more convenient.